# Sort list of dates closest to current date

Tags: c#, sorting, datetime

I have to a list of objects which has a DateTime property and I need to sort this list so that the objects with the closest date to `DateTime.Now` is first in the list.

I have tried the following:

```
nodes.Sort((x, y) => DateTime.Compare(
         DateTime.Now, 
         DateTime.Parse(x.GetProperty("date").Value)));
```

But this doesn't return a correct result.

Does anyone know of a good way to do this? :-)

Comment: Can you not just `OrderByDescending` the dates?

Comment: [First google result for "Sort Date Time c#"](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sort-datetime) - hmm...

Comment: Do you mean that you want to sort according to abs(date - Now)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can order them by the absolute difference between the node's time and the current time. You can get the absolute time of a `TimeSpan` with the [Duration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.duration.aspx) method:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
var ordered = nodes.OrderBy(n => (now - DateTime.Parse(n.GetProperty("date").Value)).Duration())
```

Comment: This! That did exactly what I needed! :-) Thanks a lot, Lee.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx)?

```
nodes.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x.GetProperty("date").Value));
```

Not sure if this would *exactly* what you are after, but if all you are trying to do is order the list by most recent date this will do the job.

Comment: Your answer assumes that no dates are in the future.

Comment: @Rotem it doesn't *assume* anything, I have stated "*if all you are trying to do is order the list by most recent date this will do the job*".

Comment: From OP: **"I need to sort this list so that the objects with the closest date to DateTime.Now is first in the list."**. Also, you added that part after my first comment.

Comment: @Rotem well I hadn't seen your comment as I was in the middle of updating my answer - yeah he want's closest to `DateTime.Now` which this answer does do, the OP makes no mention of "this has to deal with dates in the future".

Comment: Yes, sorry for not being very clear. The OrderByDescending didn't do what I needed :-) It lists the dates in i.e. 2014, 2015 etc, so.. But thanks for the input!

Comment: @James He also doesn't say that all dates are in the past, what reason would you have to assume they are. This is why I simply commented that your answer is correct only if none of the dates are in the future.

Comment: @bomortensen that's not correct, `OrderByDescending` should be sorting the dates in *descending* order, the way you have described is *ascending*. I just realised that your `GetProperty` method returns a string not a date, I have updated to parse as `DateTime`, that's possibly why the ordering was coming out wrong.

Comment: @Rotem true, but I picked *"I need to sort this list so that the objects with the closest date to DateTime.Now is first in the list."* as *"give me the most recent dates first"*, that clearly wasn't what the OP was after based on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
from node in nodes
let diff = Math.Abs(DateTime.Now.Subtract(node.DateTime).TotalSeconds)
order by diff
select date
```

Answer (score 0):

how bout

```
nodes.Sort((x,y) => Math.Abs((DateTime.Now, DateTime.Parse(x.GetProperty ("date").Value).Ticks))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        var recs = p.ReadVisitorsByMonthly();
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (var r in recs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public List<string> ReadVisitorsByMonthly()
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> retL = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        List<DateTime> liste = new List<DateTime>();
        List<string> ret = new List<string>();

        liste.Add(new DateTime(2016, 4, 1));
        liste.Add(new DateTime(2016, 4, 4));
        liste.Add(new DateTime(2016, 4, 5));
        liste.Add(new DateTime(2016, 4, 2));
        liste.Add(new DateTime(2016, 4, 3));
        liste.Add(new DateTime(2015, 11, 6));
        liste.Add(new DateTime(2015, 12, 7));
        liste.Add(new DateTime(2015, 12, 8));
        liste.Add(new DateTime(2015, 11, 4));
        liste.Add(new DateTime(2015, 12, 4));
        liste.Add(new DateTime(2016, 5, 1));
        liste.Add(new DateTime(2016, 5, 6));
        liste.Add(new DateTime(2016, 5, 2));
        liste.Add(new DateTime(2016, 5, 3));
        liste.Add(new DateTime(2016, 2, 8));
        liste.Add(new DateTime(2016, 2, 6));
        liste.Add(new DateTime(2016, 2, 2));
        liste.Add(new DateTime(2016, 2, 1));
        liste.Add(new DateTime(2016, 1, 3));
        liste.Add(new DateTime(2016, 3, 5));
        liste.Add(new DateTime(2016, 3, 4));
        liste.Add(new DateTime(2016, 3, 7));
        liste.Add(new DateTime(2016, 3, 3));
        liste.Add(new DateTime(2016, 3, 5));



        var list = liste.GroupBy(j => j.Month).ToList();

        foreach (var g in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(g.Key.ToString("D2") + " - " + g.Count());
            retL.Add(g.Key, g.Count());
        }


        var thisMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;

        var finalList = retL.OrderBy(j => (thisMonth - (j.Key > thisMonth ? j.Key - 12 : j.Key))).ToList();

        foreach (var kvp in finalList)
        {
            string strMonthName = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(kvp.Key);

            ret.Add(kvp.Key.ToString().PadRight(3) + strMonthName.PadRight(8) + kvp.Value);
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```